# Algorithm for Calculating LN(X) - Method to Reduce Arguments to Interval [1/sqrt(2), sqrt(2)]

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I have a need to implement a $\ln(x)$ function for $x>0$ for an embedded floating point library.  The expansions that I have found that will do this can be found   [here](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/qlibdoc.html#qlog) and [here](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm), however the former requires that:

> After reducing the argument into the interval $\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2}\bigg]$,
> the logarithm is calculated by .....

Is someone able to explain the mathematical approach to reducing the interval and why it is needed?

Comment: Please, use MathJax delimiters "$" not code blocks.

Comment: The question has been updated as requested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series you cite,  in ascending powers of $w=(x-1)/(x+1)$, converges quickest if $w$ is close to $0$, and not at all if $|w|>1$.  The algorithm designer picked the range of $x$ values that forces $|w|\le.172$, which is apparently good enough to ensure rapid convergence of the $w$ series.

As for how to reduce the argument.  Presumably your $x$ values are represented in the computer in normalized binary floating point form, in effect as $x=2^a y$, where $a$ is an integer and $1\le y<2$, and the values of $a$ and $y$ are available to a bit-twiddling programmer.  Then of course $\ln(x)=a\ln(2)+\ln(y)$.  If $y>1/\sqrt2$ the adjusted value $y/2$ lies in the desired range; otherwise $y$ lies in the desired range.  The calculated value of $\ln(x)$ would then be the sum of the series plus $a\ln(2)$ or $(a+1)\ln(2)$, accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the last 2 sentences - it appears to me that the range of y can be constrained appropriately by introducing a new variable y' = y/sqrt(2) thus the result would now be sum of the series y' + alog(2) +1/2*log(2).

Comment: Your procedure involves the non-trivial FP division of $y$ by $\sqrt 2$, which is possibly a bit slower than my $y/2$, and possibly subject to a tiny bit of round-off error.  Either way, I think, your original question is answered.

Comment: Yes, your original answer was what I was missing and thanks for following up.